# array explode and save

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am saving data to a mysql database and these are going to be different options, rather then having them in their own column i am trying to to keep them in the same.

So like surface in mysql would look like : grass,pavement,tarmac - i can get the data to show, but i cannot for some reason get it to save, after either adding a new option or deleting an option.

EDIT - This is now working, i reposted it on here incase others needs help! Thanks

Add:

```
    $surface = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surface']);
    $array = explode(',',$setQuery['Surface']);
    $new_array = implode(',',$array).','.$surface;
    $saveSettings = mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET Surface = '$new_array' WHERE id = '1'");
```

Delete:

```
    $surface = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['s']);
    $array = explode(',',$setQuery['Surface']);
    unset($array[$surface]);
    $new_array = implode(',',$array);
    $saveSettings = mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET Surface = '$new_array' WHERE id = '1'");
```

Thanks for any help
regards

Comment: Stop all the `for` loop nonsense to join array elements into a string and [use `implode()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)  `$new_array = implode(",", $array);`

Comment: If you had proper error handling: `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())`, you'd be told why your queries are failing.

Comment: Are you getting an error from `mysql_query()`? Check `mysql_error()`. Also, your add takes from `$_POST` while your delete takes from `$_GET`.  In neither case have you called `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the input value before querying...

Comment: why don't you use a try-catch and var_dump($saveSettings) for more info?

Comment: Not sure whether this is causing problems. But using keywords like count and array as variable names isn't a good idea.

Comment: You need to clean your code and include proper error handling. If you can't see where the error is happening, I advise with directing errors to a file like /tmp/php_errors.logs and use these statements `error_log(mysql_error())` and `error_log(print_r($array,true))` as @Michael and @Marc B mentioned above

Comment: Thanks guys, and there was no errors, it was just syntax i wasnt using the correct function for the desired result but @Michael helped and its now working, thanks

Comment: also @Michael if you post as an answer i will mark it as correct etc so you get more rep! thanks

Comment: @Sickaaron I summarized my comments into an answer. I recommend calling `mysql_real_escape_string()` later in the script, just before the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used a `for` loop to build your array into a comma-separated string sent you down the wrong path.

The correct course of action here is to use the PHP built-in [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to construct the string from your array:

```
$new_array = implode(",", $array);
```

I notice also that your `add` method reads input from `$_POST['s']` while the `delete` method reads from `$_GET['s']`. Check the consistency between these, if it is an issue.

In either case, however, you must call `mysql_real_escape_string()` to properly escape it against SQL injection.  That is best done just before inserting it into the SQL string, after you have added or deleted from the array and called `implode()`.

```
// All changes add/del made to array already...
$new_array = implode(",", $array);
$new_array = mysql_real_escape_string($new_array);

$saveSettings = mysql_query("UPDATE `settings` SET Surface = '$new_array' WHERE id = '1'");
// Use error handling methods:
if (!$saveSettings) {
  // Something went wrong
  echo mysql_error();
}
```